# Align images over a rounded rotating div

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, rotation

Considering a rounded(circle) parent div, I have to display on top of it several icons with the same width and distance between each other but they need to be parallel to the parent div.
I tried to use rotate but needs to calculate the degrees dynamically.
Also the rounded parent is spinning of 360 deg within few seconds.

My solution so far:

app.js

```
 <div> className='parent'
        {data.map((item, i) => (
          <div
            className='inner'
            key={i}
          >
            <img
              width={64}
              src={item.itemImg}
              alt={item.id}
              style={{ transformOrigin: 'center'; transform: rotate(-45deg) }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

css

```
div.parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  animation: spin 50s linear infinite;
}
```

What I have:

[image: current]

Is there a way to follow the shape of the parent ? If i hover over the element i still see a blue square

[image: current2]

Desired:

[image: desired]

Comment: a cheap way of doing this is using `position: absolute` for the books with setting top and left, right property to create this circle. there might be a better way

Comment: I hard coded this way for the desired screenshot, hopefully there is a more dynamic way since you also have to rotate each single icon

Comment: see this blog it might help. it is very similar to what u r asking https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/placing-items-circle/

Comment: here is a link to codepen with a something similar https://codepen.io/KittyGiraudel/pen/vEJXGm

Comment: Do the books also rotate with the circle or do they stay where they are?

Comment: They need to move and follow the circle and each book or icons need to be perfectly parallel to the circle border.
The problem i also came across is that there are different icons and they might need a different rotation and positioning to be aligned.
I think the positioning and rotation is constantly updating but not sure how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS way of doing it.

Each book div is a rectangle which sits with its bottom on the center of the circle and is 20% higher than the radius of the circle.

Each of these rectangles has a background image (in this case of a book) at the top.

The rectangle is rotated a number of degrees depending on what child number it is. This snippet uses 22.5 degrees as the base.

[image]

The whole thing is rotated so the books stay in the same relative position to the parent circle and their bases are parallel to a tangent to the circle.

Obviously you will want to change the dimensions, positoning etc to suit your use case.

```css
.container {
  /* positioned in center of viewport just for demo */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  --r: 20vmin;
  /* radius of the circle */
  --t: 8;
  /* total number of books */
  position: relative;
  --w: calc(var(--r) * 1.2);
  /* the top of the book is 20% out further than the edge of the circle */
  width: calc(2 * var(--w));
  height: calc(2 * var(--w));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(2 * var(--r));
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--r) * 0.2);
  left: calc(var(--r) * 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.book {
  height: calc(var(--r) * 1.2);
  width: calc(var(--r) / 5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: var(--w);
  left: calc(var(--w) - (0.5 * var(--r) / 5));
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--n) * 22.5deg));
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XtVu.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.book:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.book:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.book:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.book:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.book:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.book:nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
}

.book:nth-child(7) {
  --n: 7;
}

.book:nth-child(8) {
  --n: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="book"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution, is working but I now also have to align a related icon for each book but this time inside the circle, same properties as the books, so parallel to the circle.
I will accept your answer as the right one, thanks :-)

Comment: Just do the same again but with less tall rectangles.

Comment: yes I did it, fantastic