# How can I create a circular arc of icons around a floating action button with clickable tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a web project and I have a floating action button that is positioned at either the bottom right or bottom left corner of the screen. When I click on this button, four icons are displayed vertically above the button.

Currently, the icons appear in a vertical layout above the floating action button. However, I want the icons to be arranged in a circular arc around the button, maintaining their vertical order. Additionally, I would like to implement clickable tooltips for each icon, showing some information when the user hovers over them.

Code Sanbox Link
https://codepen.io/Markshall/pen/wQyWqq

Below is the image of my requirement.
[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.adminActions {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 35px;
}

.adminButton {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(67, 83, 143, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.adminButton i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.adminButtons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 120%;
  text-align: center;
}

.adminButtons a {
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  line-height: 1.15;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, .3);
}

.adminButtons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.adminButtons a:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out .3s, transform .15s ease-in-out;
}

.adminButtons a:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out .25s, transform .15s ease-in-out;
}

.adminButtons a:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f44336;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out .2s, transform .15s ease-in-out;
}

.adminButtons a:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out .15s, transform .15s ease-in-out;
}

.adminActions a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.adminToggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, .3);
}

.adminToggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 2px rgba(51, 51, 51, .3);
}

.adminToggle:checked~.adminButtons a {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="adminActions">
  <input type="checkbox" name="adminToggle" class="adminToggle" />
  <a class="adminButton" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
  <div class="adminButtons">
    <a href="#" title="Add Company"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></a>
    <a href="#" title="Edit Company"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></a>
    <a href="#" title="Add User"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried and where do you get stuck? You might find some [helpful ideas around StackOverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+how+to+position+elements+in+an+arc+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Look into CSS rotate and transform-origin.

Comment: This shows how to place elements around a circle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371311/align-images-over-a-rounded-rotating-div

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample code, it resolves the issue of sort like a circle (you can do the tooltip part, it is easy and it will take more work than I spend answering)

Think in angles like a clock, from right to left so the elements will appear in that order

```js
const conatiner = document.querySelector(".btn-container");
const btn = conatiner.querySelector(".btn");
let hideTimeout = null;

const distance = 64; // distance circles from center
const from = 0.5; // half angle // start angle
const to = 0.75; // 75% of full angle // end angle

conatiner.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
  const btnSecondarys = conatiner.querySelectorAll(".btn-secondary");
  const steps = (to - from) / (btnSecondarys.length - 1);
  
  btnSecondarys.forEach((element, x) => {
    const percentAngle = from + (steps * x);    
    const angle = (Math.PI * 2) * percentAngle;

    element.style.top = (Math.sin(angle) * distance) + 'px';
    element.style.left = (Math.cos(angle) * distance) + 'px';
    element.style.opacity = 1;
  });
});

conatiner.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    conatiner.querySelectorAll(".btn-secondary").forEach(element => {
      element.style.top = 0;
      element.style.left = 0;
      element.style.opacity = 0;
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.btn-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 999rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.btn-secondary {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  transform: translateX(0.25rem) translateY(0.25rem);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="btn">A</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">B</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">C</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">D</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">E</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">F</button>
</div>
```